A website is trying to sell my intellectual property. I'm not involved
I'm a user of the online platform Musescore, which enables users to upload music that they have created in the Musescore app to the website (musescore.com). Some users of the platform also sell their music on it--I do not do this. The website allows anyone on the internet to view the scores, and listen to an auto-generated audio of the scores, but it does not allow non-owners to download the sheet music--at least not without paying for it.
I recently logged into my account to check on one of my recently updated scores, and found something rather surprising... I was logged in, but on the bottom left of the screen was a banner encouraging me to "buy this score to get full access":

For context, this is my score--my own original work. I haven't given Musescore any permission to sell my sheet music, nor have I inputted any bank information to which Musescore could send any revenue accrued from selling my music. My only conclusion is that Musescore is trying to sell my intellectual property and make a profit off of it without my permission. What should I do?

Just to add a little more context: I have tried reloading the page multiple times, and confirmed that I am signed in with the correct account.

Read 7.2 of https://musescore.com/legal/terms You granted Musescore the license to do that.

This question is similar to: Is musescore.com violating CC-BY-NC by requiring a paid account to download such files?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"What should I do?" is a request for legal advice, which this site cannot provide.  https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221

The Muse Score User Agreement section 7.2 says:

By posting any User Generated Content on, through or in connection with the Service, you hereby grant to MuseScore a limited license to use, modify, delete from, add to, publicly perform, publicly display, reproduce, and distribute such User Generated Content. [...] Except as expressly provided for herein, this limited license does not grant MuseScore the right to sell or otherwise distribute your User Generated Content outside of the Service.

By accepting this user agreement, you gave Muse Score the permission to sell your work to anyone on this service.
